# Deduplicating overlapping borders?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I've got a gpkg file with country borders and I'd like to draw a dashed line for those borders. However, when I set the style as a dashed line in QGIS I get this:

[image]

The problem is that the overlapping portions (the vertical section above where the dashed line looks almost solid) show up incorrectly. Is there an easy way to fix this with QGIS/GDAL/something else?